# Django database query acting unexpectedly

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a website with these models:

```
class TrainingSession(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(user)
    active_exercise = models.ForeignKey(Exercise)

class Passage(models.Model):
    text = models.TextField()

class Exercise(models.Model):
    training_session = models.ForeignKey(TrainingSession)
    passage = models.ForeignKey(Passage)
```

where a user is assigned a `TrainingSession` that generates exercises of passages.

The general idea of the website is to give users reading exercises to work on.  But I want to generate new exercises with passages the users haven't read yet during their current session.  So to that end, the `TrainingSession` class has this method:

```
# this passes
def generate_exercise(self):
   passages = Passage.objects.exclude(exercise__trainingsession=self)
   if not passages:
       raise ObjectDoesNotExist()
   passage = random.choice(passages)
   new_exercise = Exercise.objects.create(training_session=self,
                                          passage=passage)
   self.active_exercise = new_exercise
```

So if I tried to generate an exercise before creating any passages, you'd expect an `ObjectDoesNotExist` to be raised.  And that's exactly what happens in this test:

```
# this test passes
def test_no_passages(self):
    Passage.objects.all().delete()
    user = User.objects.create()
    session = TrainingSession.objects.create(user=user)
    with self.assertRaises(ObjectDoesNotExist):
        session.generate_exercise()
```

And if I have one passage, and generate the exercise, it works:

```
# this test passes
def test_generate_one(self):
    Passage.objects.all().delete()
    user = User.objects.create()
    session = TrainingSession.objects.create(user=user)
    Passage.objects.create(passage_title='a', passage_text='b')
    session.generate_exercise()
```

And if I have one passage, and try to generate two exercises in a row, it raises the exception, as I'd hoped:

```
# this test passes
def test_cant_generate_second(self):
    Passage.objects.all().delete()
    user = User.objects.create()
    session = TrainingSession.objects.create(user=user)
    Passage.objects.create(passage_title='a', passage_text='b')
    session.generate_exercise()
    with self.assertRaises(ObjectDoesNotExist):
        session.generate_exercise()
```

But then if I have TWO passages, and try to generate THREE exercises, no error gets raised and this following test fails:

```
# never raises the exception and fails
def test_cant_generate_third(self):
    Passage.objects.all().delete()
    user = User.objects.create()
    session = TrainingSession.objects.create(user=user)
    Passage.objects.create(passage_title='a', passage_text='b')
    Passage.objects.create(passage_title='c', passage_text='d')
    session.generate_exercise()
    session.generate_exercise()
    with self.assertRaises(ObjectDoesNotExist):
        session.generate_exercise()
```

And if I print out what should be the 'used' passages:

```
print 'used:', [ex.passage for ex in
    Exercise.objects.filter(trainingsession=session)]
```

at different points in the last test, something weird happens.  At first it's empty, when I haven't generated any exercises.  After I generate the first exercise, it prints out an array with the passage attached to the first generated exercise.  But when I generate a second exercise, it ONLY SHOWS THE NEWEST EXERCISES'S PASSAGE.  So somehow,

```
Exercise.objects.filter(trainingsession=session)
```

is only finding the latest created exercise, and not all the exercises that I've created pointing to the given training session.

So my question is: might there be a reason why the line:

```
new_exercise = Exercise.objects.create(training_session=self,
                                       passage=passage)
```

might cause this later query:

```
passages = Passage.objects.exclude(exercise__trainingsession=self)
```

to misbehave?

I already tried:

```
new_exercise.save() # --doesn't help
```

Or, if that question doesn't have an obvious answer, my follow up: can you see what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out:

```
passages = Passage.objects.exclude(exercise__trainingsession=self)
```

should be

```
passages = Passage.objects.exclude(exercise__training_session=self)
```

Using

```
exercise__trainingsession
```

was following the reverse path from TrainingSession to Exercise through TrainingSession's active_exercise foreign key, so only the 'active' exercise was being excluded.